# Sympy Attribute Error: module 'sympy' has no attribute 'derive_by_array'

Tags: jupyter-notebook, sympy, attributeerror

I keep receiving this error when trying to derive using sympy.
I have updated sympy using Anaconda Prompt and "conda update sympy" but it made no change when trying to use the derive_by_array function in jupyter-notebook. Perhaps the update isn't registering in jupyter?
What can I do to fix this issue?

Here is a general example of the code where I receive the error:

```
    import sympy as sp
    x= sp.symbols('x')
    f = x**2
    sp.derive_by_array(f,x)
```

Comment: The example works for me. What version of sympy are you using?

Answer (score 1):

After removing using Anaconda Prompt then installing a newer version of Anaconda, sympy started working.